# Datetime to utc format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this `DateTime` format:

```
var1 = 2014-06-10T18:49:59+00:00
```

and I want convert to this format:

```
var2 = 2014-06-10 18:49:59 UTC
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Time.parse(var1.to_s).utc
```

Assuming var1 holds a DateTime object.

Comment: Thank you it's the best response for me. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Use strftime:

```
var2 = var1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")
```

see the strftime documentation for more format strings

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html